# Why my width: 100% wrapper doesn't work properly?

Tags: css

I put all my content in wrapper that 100% width. my wrapper is not a child.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
    <?php require_once("content.php"); ?>
    <?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
overflow-x: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color:#fff5e5;
}
```

But browser (chrome, moz) shows that:

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: localhost. auto height didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element in your page is rendering outside of `<body>` element. This can be the result of many causes (negative margins, large widths, large paddings) and guessing it is waste of time. Create a [`minimal, complete and verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll find it in minutes.

If you don't care what is the cause and only want to remove the effect, (which is clearly the wrong way to go about it and ***I strongly advise against***), you can always apply

```
body {
  oveflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right the problem was in a negative margin.

Answer (score 0):

If it is main wrapper,Only adding

```
display:block;
```

must solve your issue.

Comment: The  information you provided is not enough to solve it

Comment: it is all on my machine. i use xampp. I share all related code, what kind of information do you want?

Comment: First can you add border:2px red solid; to your code

Comment: I guess it is not wrapper problem but content inside

Comment: Can you please add that border to body and see what happens. If it draw on correct place it means you have a wrong padding or margin on right hand side of wrapper

Comment: I also have that code there:
* {
 
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 outline:none;
}
html {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;

}

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if your content inside of the wrapper takes up 100% of the space. If you hover over the element in the debug, a blue box will show up. If it is 100% of the width, then that means that the content inside probably only spans part of the screen width.